# Invalid Data Type Specified

Tags: matlab

'

Hello, I am trying to write a for loop that will search through my one-column array for the symbol "[]" or an empty numeric array. However, I keep getting this error when I search for [] : "Abnormal exit: Invalid data type specified. Data type can be Advisor.Element objects or character vector." I really have no idea why this is happening. When I search for a value like "1" or "2", it seems to work.

```
for x = 1:1:n
if(names_en{1,x} == "[]")
display(new_block_name_enable{x,1}); % finds [] and displays location
end
end
```

Comment: Do you actually have the string "[]" in the cell array, or do you really have just empty elements that display as []? What if you tried if( isempty(names_en{1,x}) ) instead?

Comment: I believe they are empty elements that display as []. I though so too, but when I tried the solution `isempty`, it wouldn't recognize cells with [],

Comment: What about using single quotes for a char array instead of double quotes for a string variable? E.g., try isequal(names_en{1,x},'[]'). Can you examine one of these cells to determine the actual data type and value?